# How to measure MongoDB query execution time from Java application

Tags: java, mongodb, execution-time

I am writing a small utility to benchmark databases. There is a small snippet showing how I execute query. ( I am using java driver for MongoDB):

```
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        MongoIterable<Document> execResult = peopleCollection.aggregate(Collections.singletonList(group));
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = execResult.cursor();

        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            cursor.next();
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I want to correctly measure the time in order to have reliable tests. When I delete the *while* loop, the time is shorter, but it returns only the first batch of results. Does the query executes completely and server returns results in batches or it executes another time when getting next batch?

In my opinion both approaches are a little bit unreliable and I cannot find any information how to measure time from Java application.

I cannot use .explain() or server logging to extract the time, I need to do it from Java application. I searched for answers in stack but nothing found.

Thanks for any hep in advance!

Comment: Use command monitoring.

Comment: I think that you need to make up your mind on what does the "query execution time" means. When you do a query that returns plenty of rows, database does not generate all of them proactively, but waits until you actually ask for them using the cursor. If you do "SELECT * from Table" with 100k rows, it will most likely spend most of them time returning rows. However if the query is very complex and returns just one integer, both times should be more/less in line.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not an actual execution time. It also contains time of data transportation. So the question might be: if I ask cursor for the next batch of data - does it execute query once again or it stores all the records and returns to the user in batches?

Answer (score 0):

AggregateIterable agg = order_collection.aggregate(Collections.singleton(T));

Document explain=agg.explain();

MongoCursor mongoCursor=agg.cursor();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).